# A converse of Lagrange Mean value theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be continuous function , diferentiable in $(a,b)$ and $c \in (a,b)$ be such that $f'(c)$

is not a local extreme value of $f'(x)$ in $(a,b)$ and $c$ is not an accumulation point of

$\{x \in(a,b):f'(x)=f'(c)\}$ ; then how to prove that there is a subinterval $(a_1,b_1) \subseteq (a,b)$

containing $c$ such that $f'(c)=\dfrac{f(b_1)-f(a_1)}{b_1-a_1}$ ?

Comment: See the paper by Tong and Braza published on the Amer. Math. Monthly (Dec. 1997).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Make life a little easier and assume $[a,b]=[-1,1], f(0)=0=f'(0).$ Then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $f'\ne 0$ in $(-\epsilon,0)\cup(0,\epsilon).$ By Darboux, $f'$ is of one sign on $(-\epsilon,0);$ same for $(0,\epsilon).$ Could we have $f'> 0$ to the left and $f'>0$ to the right?